# Javascript calculator value

Tags: javascript, calculator

Below I have Javascript code (a calculator). Also I have several inputs (`<input name="roip" value="xxxx" class="input c2" type="text">`). What should I write in value (value"xxxx" )?

This is my HTML:

```
<input name="amount" value="xxxx" onchange="calculate()"  type="text">
<input name="roip" value="xxxx" class="input c2" type="text">
<input name="ret" value="xxxx" class="input c2" type="text">
```

And my Javascript:

```
function calculate() {
    c = new Array(1, 10, 500, 104, 1, 501, 2000, 105, 1, 2001, 5000, 106, 1, 5001, );
    a = document.calc.amount.value
    p = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i += 4) {
        if (c[i] == document.calc.plan.selectedIndex + 1) {
            if ((a >= c[i + 1]) && (a <= c[i + 2])) p = c[i + 3];
        }
    }
    if (p == 0) {
        p = '-';
        a = '-';
    } else {
        a = a * p / 100;
    }
    document.calc.roip.value = p;
    document.calc.ret.value = a;

}
calculate();
```

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript; this looks more like JavaScript than Java.

Comment: Yes , you right, this is java script ( sorry i'm new in here )

Comment: No worries. I have retagged the question for other people's benefit.

Comment: thankyou , i want add new question by more details now

Answer (score 0):

Write whatever you think is a good default/example value or don't supply a default. Alternatively you could have a message like "type amount here" which is cleared when the user first clicks the textbox.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The `value="xxxx"` will only set what appears in the text input when the document loads to xxxx. Are you having difficulty with getting the correct value?

Answer (score 0):

are you asking how to display the results in the inputs?

you don't need to assign a value to your inputs, because the js function is getting the values ( document.getValueByName('amount').value )

you can use :

to display the value zero as default value